# How to get IKpictureTaker panel, select the file event

Tags: objective-c, macos, ikpicturetaker

I use `IKPictureTaker` when it encounters a doubt, I hope in

`[pictureTaker beginPictureTakerSheetForWindow: app.window withDelegate: self didEndSelector: @ selector (pictureTakerValidated: code: contextInfo :) contextInfo: nil];`

appear after running a panel, then you can select the default, the most recently used, camera, the other four options.

My first question is: How to get the select event of each option? I need to be able to respond after selecting.

The second problem is that this option is selected the other, a pop-up to select a picture from a file inside a window, how to set the selected image type, such as only allowing users to choose JPG, JPEG, BMP ... file format, other the ban users selected.

The third question is, how do I get this event to open the file selection window?